# "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database"

Tags: sql, database, debugging

I am getting an error when I try to go to my website (Hosted with XAMPP):

> ```
> database 'chat' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\index.php:23 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\index.php(23):
> PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\index.php on line 23
> ```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ideas to help you :

1. Please recheck your MySQL credentials (host, user and password);
2. Check if your user is allowed to read/write on the desired database (root should be...);
3. Check if the database named "chat" is present in your MySQL server.

Can you provide us an exact list of the current databases on the server ?

Comment: Where is the database?

Comment: Your error shows that there is a "chat" name database which was not found. Check on PhpMyAdmin if "chat" is present on the server.

Comment: Yes, in my case, the database simply did not exist.